# What type of predictive analysis should I use in R?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, predictive-models, interaction

In my study, there are a continuous dependent variable (fluency scores) and a continuous independent variable as a predictor (anxiety scores). I also include some task conditions (e.g., simple vs. complex tasks; planning vs. no planning; first performance vs. second performance). My focus is on the predicative power of anxiety on fluency scores under each task condition (simple, complex, planning, no planning ,...) and a combination of task conditions (e.g., simple + planning, complex +planning,...); in other words, I want to examine under which task conditions, anxiety has a strong predicative power on fluency. I also want to consider random effects of participants if possible.

Which type of analysis should I use in `R`? (panel linear regression? moderated multiple regression model? mixed-effect model?"

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a multilevel (mixed model) regression with fluency as dependent and anxiety, each task condition, and each condition x anxiety interaction as predictor, and including a random effect of participant. You can see examples by checking out R lmer or lme tutorials. However estimating many interactions requires a lot of data - what is your sample size? How many task conditions did you have? And were the conditions within- or between-participants?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have both within- or between-comparisons, and the sample size is 90. Tak conditions are as follows: task complexity with 2 levels and task readiness with 2 levels (as between subject variables) and task iteration (as within subject variable). Anxiety as predictive variable and fluency as dependent variable. When I use this formula: Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety* taskreadiness* Taskcomplexity * Taskiteration + (1|participants), does the output provides information on the degree of the predicative power of anxiety on fluency under each condition?

Comment: The model you have planned seems reasonable to me. However your N is rather small for estimating this many parameters. But yes, your model would tell you the relation between anxiety and fluency in different task conditions.

Comment: You may want to consider only putting in each task conditions 2-way interaction with anxiety (or, even better, if you can think of theoretically most meaningful interaction combinations and use those instead of all possible ones). That would make the relation between your N and number of estimated parameters reasonable.

Comment: you mean, I use the following formulas (instead of one four-way-interaction formula): 

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety* taskreadiness + (1|participants)

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety*Taskcomplexity + (1|participants)

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety* Taskiteration + (1|participants)

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety* taskreadiness* Taskcomplexity + (1|participants)

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety* taskreadiness*  Taskiteration + (1|participants)

Data <- lmer(fluency~ anxiety*  Taskcomplexity * Taskiteration + (1|participants)

Comment: Please edit the body of your question to add additional context and information that you've given in the comments. It makes it easier for everyone to follow this thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Re: your last comment: no, you definitely shouldn't run separate models for different predictors.

I was thinking more along the lines of

```
model<-lmer(fluency ~ (1|participant) + taskcomplexity * anxiety + taskreadiness * anxiety + taskiteration * anxiety, data=data)
```

If complexity, readiness and iteration all have two levels, and you enter the 4-way interaction, your model estimates 16 parameters, which is a lot with 90 participants. If any of your predictors has more than 2 levels, the number of estimated parameters is even larger. The model I suggested only estimates 8 parameters (if each categorical predictor has 2 levels), and still gives you the interaction effects between anxiety and other predictors.

However I don't know anything about your subject matter, so if you're confident you need to estimate the 4-way interaction and feel your data is large enough, you should do it (and if you have 90 participants in a repeated measure setting you have at least 180 observations, so it might not be that bad.).